# Rally SDK 2 custom sorters

Tags: extjs, rally

How do I get a more complex sort on a query, I have this query currently:

```
    var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store',{
        data: changes,
        limit: 'Infinity',
        pageSize: 5000,
        sorters: [
            { 
                property: 'ReleaseScope',
                direction: 'ASC'
            },
            {
                property: 'ScheduleState',
                direction: 'DESC'
            }
        ]

    });
```

Because the ScheduleState is hydrated I can't sort by the normal numerics, can I define the order using some kind of matcher?

i.e. say I want to show in order [Accepted, Completed, In-Progress, Defined, Backlog]
And, if I wanted to complicate this further and show stories with story points first, something like

```
All stories with a story point value != 0
    Sorted by schedulestate [accepted, completed, in-progress, defined  etc..]
stories with no story point value
    some other sort here possibly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a sorterFn rather than a property/direction combo to implement custom sort logic:

```
sorters: [
    {
        sorterFn: function(a, b) {
            var scheduleStates = ['Accepted', 'Completed', 'In-Progress', 'Defined'],
            aState = a.get('ScheduleState'),
            aIndex = _.indexOf(scheduleStates, aState),
            bState = b.get('ScheduleState'),
            bIndex = _.indexOf(scheduleStates, bState);
            return a - b;
        }
    }
]
```

The above function should sort them based on schedule state descending I think.